# PHP Form checkbox question

Tags: php

I have a form that takes the following inputs:
Name: IBM
Surface(in m^2): 9
Floor:      (Checkbox1)
Phone:    (Checkbox2)
Network:  (Checkbox3)
Button to send to a next php page.

All those values above are represented in a table when i press the submit button.
The first two (name and surname) are properly displayed in the table.
**The problem is with the checkboxes.**  If i select the first checkbox the value in the table should be presented with 1.  If its not selected the value in the table should be empty.

```
 echo "<td>$Name</td>"; // works properly
 echo "<td>$Surface</td>"; // works properly
 echo "<td>....no idea for the checkboxes</td>;
```

Some part of my php code with the variables:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST))
{
$name= $_POST["name"];
$surface= $_POST["surface"];
$floor= $_POST["floor"]; 
$phone= $_POST["telefoon"]; 
$network= $_POST["netwerk"]; 


if (is_numeric($surface)) 
{
    $_SESSION["name"]=$name;
    $_SESSION["surface"]=$surface;
    header("Location:ExpoOverzicht.php"); 
}
else 
{
    echo "<h1>Wrong input, Pleasee fill in again</h1>";
}  

if(!empty($floor) && ($phone) && ($network))
{
    $_SESSION["floor"]=$floor;
    $_SESSION["phone"]=$phone;
    $_SESSION["network"]=$network;
    header("Location:ExpoOverzicht.php"); 
}    
}

?>
```

Second page with table:

```
<?php

$name= $_SESSION["name"];
$surface= $_SESSION["surface"];
$floor= $_SESSION["floor"];
$phone= $_SESSION["phone"];
$network= $_SESSION["network"];

echo "<table class=\"tableExpo\">";

echo "<th>name</th>";
echo "<th>surface</th>";
echo "<th>floor</th>";
echo "<th>phone</th>";
echo "<th>network</th>";
echo "<th>total price</th>";

for($i=0; $i <= $_SESSION["name"]; $i++)
{
    echo "<tr>";

        echo "<td>$name</td>"; // gives right output
        echo "<td>$surface</td>"; // gives right output
        echo "<td>...</td>"; //wrong output (ment for checkbox 1)
        echo "<td>...</td>"; //wrong output (ment for checkbox 2)
        echo "<td>...</td>"; //wrong output (ment for checkbox 3)
        echo "<td>....</td>";

    echo "</tr>;";
}
echo "</table>";



<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" id="form1">
<h1>Vul de gegevens in</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" size="18"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Surface(in m^2):</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="surface" size="6"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Floor:</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="floor" value="floor"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone:</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="phone" value="phone"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Network:</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="network" value="network"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="verzenden" value="Verzenden"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There might be a few spelling mistakes since i had to translate it.
Best regards.

Comment: And your html code looks like ???

Comment: added the form html code. Everything is in 2 php files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of directly assigning your checkbox variables, see if they have been checked or not first.

```
$verdieping = isset($_POST["floor"]) ? $_POST["floor"] : 0; 
$telefoon = isset($_POST["telefoon"]) ? $_POST["telefoon"] : 0; 
$netwerk = isset($_POST["netwerk"]) ? $_POST["netwerk"] : 0;
```

This way, if the user hasn't ticked a checkbox, you have a value of '0' assigned to it instead of an undefined variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a checkbox with:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" value="1">
```

you can check the value after submitting the form by:

```
if(!empty($_POST["mycheckbox"])) {
    // checkbox was checked
}
else {
    // checkbox was not checked
}
```

Comment: Hello, have that in my first php file. But what exactly do i put in my table td element to call upon that value?

Answer (score 1):

In this php page you can write like this, it may be solution of your question

```
if (!empty($_POST))
{
$standnaam = $_POST["name"];
$oppervlakte = $_POST["surface"];
$verdieping = $_POST["floor"]; 
$telefoon = $_POST["telefoon"]; 
$netwerk = $_POST["netwerk"]; 


if (is_numeric($oppervlakte)) 
{
    $_SESSION["name"]=$standnaam;
    $_SESSION["surface"]=$oppervlakte;
    header("Location:ExpoOverzicht.php"); 
}
else 
{
    echo "<h1>Wrong input, Pleasee fill in again</h1>";
}  

if(!empty($verdieping) && ($telefoon) && ($netwerk))
{
    $_SESSION["floor"]=$verdieping;
    $_SESSION["phone"]=$telefoon;
    $_SESSION["network"]=$netwerk;
    header("Location:ExpoOverzicht.php"); 
}    
}
```